# How to use Pumping Lemma $L = \{ wsw \mid w \in \{0,1\}^*, s \in \{2\}^* \text{, and } |w| = 2 \cdot |s| \}$?

Tags: turing-machines, regular-languages, context-free, proof-techniques, pumping-lemma

I'm trying to use the Pumping Lemma to prove that $L = \{ wsw \mid w \in \{0,1\}^*,\ s \in \{2\}^*\text{ and } |w| = 2\cdot|s| \}$ is not a CFL.

Comment: You may want to improve the notations. Use "\{" to display a "{" inside "\$  \$" environment.

Comment: Have you read [how to ask a good homework question?](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1284/how-do-i-ask-a-good-homework-question)? The problem in the question can be considered as a homework question. Besides a thoughtful question, it is expected of you to show your partial progress, thoughts or where you got stuck. Otherwise, this post is likely to be downvoted or closed, as posts that simply dump problems are discouraged

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lets choose $ z = (01)^n2^n(01)^n$ when $n$ is the constant of the lemma

$ z = uvwxy,\ |vx|\geq1,\ |vwx|\leq n,\ uv^iwx^iy\in L$

The core concept is to prove that all possible disassemling is not pumpable for this $z$

case 1: $u=(01)^s, vwx = (01)^t,\ s,t\leq n,\ y=(01)^{n-t}2^n(01)^n \rightarrow uv^iw^ixy \notin L$ because letters added with $i$ are not added to the second $w$.

case 2: $vwx = (01)^t2^s,\ s+t\leq n,\ y=2^{n-s-t}(01)^n $

sub case 2.1: if both $v,x$ are $\in 2^*,\ uv^iw^ixy \notin L$ because $|w|\not=2⋅|s|$

sub case 2.2: $x$ or $v$ contain $\{0,1\}^*$ so the first $w$ will be different after pumping

from case 3 it kinda goes pretty much the same